# Split multiple multi valued columns to separate tables using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I tried searching for solutions online but couldn't come far. I'm using SSIS to migrate xlsx datasets(2 of them) to own SQL database.
This is my dataset: [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTBqx.png). Downloaded from: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/shivamb/amazon-prime-movies-and-tv-shows

As you can see, single table with multiple multi-valued columns. So I normalized this into tables with like Director, Actor, Country with association to table Product.

I followed this article for the migration: http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/11/split-multi-value-column-into-multiple.html

There are other articles and suggestions that uses the same solution.

My problem is that the Script Component is not working. This is the error I get:
[Script Component Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFAQm.png)

With the following script: [script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAfjy.png)

I commented out the example code since I don't have State column but you might also notice that I only have director as a single input from source and output as regisseur.[SSIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC3Xz.png) My idea is that there is no record of regisseur in the destination database, which is the reason for the error message saying 'object reference not set to instance of an object'. The regisseur table has a PK Identity and a name for the Director's name.

Any ideas? I can do the rest of the database migration if I can fix this problem.

EDIT: I forgot to mention a possible solution in this article: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/a-super-easy-way-to-generate-new-records-from-multi-value-columns-using-excels-power-query/

This would create a lot of records in the source file. When migrating these data to their own tables in my SQL database, tables like Product would have lots of duplicates. Which is another issue, if the article is of any solution.

But I don't know if this is possible, I don't have experience in this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is to use the commands "TOKENCOUNT" and "TOKEN" and combine with "Foreach Loop Container" and "For Loop Container".

Using "TOKENCOUNT", find the number of separators to determine the number of loop executions. In "For Loop Container" you can use "TOKEN" to separate the data. Next, run the Insert script using the data obtained.